# How to enable correct charset HTTP-header in NGINX

Tags: nginx, http, charset

What is the right way to enable correct charset headers in NGINX?

I'm analyzing my website with Google Page Speed. [It says that I should specify the charset of HTML files in HTTP-headers.](http://pagespeed.googlelabs.com/pagespeed/#url=vorb.de&mobile=false&rule=SpecifyCharsetEarly) What is the right way to do this?

I already tried to set `charset utf-8;` in the `server {}` declaration of my NGINX configuration file, but it hasn't got any effect.

My server responds with the following header:

```
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Fri, 16 Sep 2011 12:43:24 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 02 Sep 2011 15:13:17 GMT
Server: nginx/0.7.67
```

Thank you.

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Link to documentation of the *SpecifyCharsetEarly* rule: https://code.google.com/archive/p/page-speed/wikis/SpecifyCharsetEarly.wiki ([archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20170102084035/https://code.google.com/archive/p/page-speed/wikis/SpecifyCharsetEarly.wiki))

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Adding `charset utf-8;` is pretty much everything you need to do. Are sure that you didn't forget to reload **nginx** after you changed the configuration file?

Besides at the moment of writing, `curl -I https://vorb.de/` returns the following result:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/0.7.67
Date: Fri, 16 Sep 2011 13:20:03 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1705
Last-Modified: Fri, 02 Sep 2011 15:13:17 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

So everything looks ok now.

Answer (score 29):

Setting the charset might not work if you do not set "charset_types" directive which you want UTF-8.

For example: When you set "charset utf-8;", all HTML will reflect, but not JSON files, because they are not set by default on "charset_types".

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_charset_module.html#charset_types

Answer (score 7):

This is all you need.

```
charset utf-8;
source_charset utf-8;
```

It won't work for me unless I have both.

Comment: @giacomo1968, don't edit the grammar in my answer just so you can get points or something.

Comment: “…don't edit the grammar in my answer just so you can get points or something…” I didn’t edit your grammar to “get points or something.” I edited your grammar to improve your answer. I didn’t change the content of your answer for any reason but to improve very basic formatting and text. If you [actually look at the edits](https://serverfault.com/posts/975289/revisions) you can see I barely changed anything. But if you don’t like it, you are free to roll back the edits. The Stack Exchange sites allow community members to edit any question/answer to improve it. And you can always it roll back.

Answer (score 6):

You might have to also adjust the `charset_types` setting to include the mime type you want to set the charset setting for (e.g. text/calendar is not included there by default).

For what it's worth I think that `text/*` should be handled by default - but you cannot use it here (as with Apache IIRC).

See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_charset_module.html#charset_types